# Parsing date from string in regional format

Tags: php

I have Mysql table, with dates, represented as "4 мар. 2023 г." ("мар." - is russian March)
I need to parse this date in PHP, and format it like Y-m-d.
Trying:

```
$formatter = new IntlDateFormatter("ru_RU", IntlDateFormatter::SHORT, IntlDateFormatter::NONE);
$unixtime=$formatter->parse($dta);
echo date('Y-m-d', $unixtime);
```

But the result is not correct. Is there the other way?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can provide a custom pattern to `IntlDateFormatter` that is used for both formatting and parsing dates as the 6th argument.

However, the abbreviation you provided for March, мар, does not appear to be correct. Every translation site shows it as март. Using мар will not work with the INTL library either. It must be март or the parse will fail. Additionally, I don't know what that final 'г' is at the end. Translations ignore it, but you can add it in specifically as required text if you need it.

For the formatting symbols that you can use, look at the [ICU Documentation site](https://unicode-org.github.io/icu/userguide/format_parse/datetime/#datetime-format-syntax).

(Note that the symbols are not always the same as the standard `DateTime`/date formatting in PHP since the INTL library is a wrapper for the ICU library. It doesn't use the same date parsing/formatting code that standard PHP does)

```php
$formatter = new IntlDateFormatter(
    "ru_RU",
    IntlDateFormatter::SHORT,
    IntlDateFormatter::NONE,
    null,
    null,
    'd LLL. yyyy'
);
/*
 * $dta must start with a 1-2 decimal day of month
 *     followed by the correct abbreviation of the month and a period
 *     followed by a 4-digit year.
 * Example: '4 март. 2023'
*/
$unixtime=$formatter->parse($dta);
echo date('Y-m-d', $unixtime); // 2023-03-04
```

Comment: Thank you. All months are ok, and the problem with "мар." solved with str_replace.